# how to set multiple alarms using sqlite data?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am new to android ,here I am developing an alarm app for my working knowledge .

I have completed the following :

- creating alarms and storing it into sqlite database.
- Fetching all the alarms which has the status as active .

I have tried many stackoverflow post and their solutions and other blog posts which related to my doubt but I can't get a solution for my problem .

What is my problem is I am receiving number of alarm timings from sqlite database which I have set it before and I want to set all the alarms on the stored time .

Here I don't know how to set it .

Can anyone help me to set the multiple alarms .

I am really looking for someone's help to learn and experience these things please help me .

Thanks.

Comment: U need alarm manager and pending intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Alarm Manager and Pending Intent more.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ActivemyAlarms.size(); i++) {

            int mHour = 0,mMin=0;
            String amPm = null;
            int mAlarmId = ActivemyAlarms.get(i).getALARM_ID(); //each alarm has an unique Id ,for differentiate one from another
            String mAlarmTime = ActivemyAlarms.get(i).getALARM_TIME(); // alarm time (11:12:AM)


            if (!(mAlarmTime == null)) {
                String mtime = mAlarmTime;  // alarm time format is 12hr format (ex : 11:12:AM)
                String[] time = mtime.split(":");
                mHour = Integer.parseInt(time[0].trim()); // get 11 hour
                mMin = Integer.parseInt(time[1].trim()); // get 12 min
                amPm = ((time[2].trim()));
            }
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, amPm!=null && amPm.equalsIgnoreCase("pm")?(mHour+12):mHour);
            calendar.set(calendar.MINUTE, mMin);
            calendar.set(calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calendar.set(calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

            Intent intent = new Intent(this,AlarmReceiver.class); //calling my Alarm service class which plays a music on the specific time
            final int _id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis(); // get calendar instance

            //Use Alarm manager and Pending Intent

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, mAlarmId, intent, 0);

            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
```

}

And to cancel any Alarm call alarmManager.cancel(PendingIntent) like;

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, mAlarmId, intent, 0);
alarmManager.cancel(alarmIntent);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ...!@Mangal

Comment: Here I am facing an issue ,I can't stop the alarm sound it's keep running after clicking on the stop button .